# How to check if a user exists in a group

Tags: 2007, permissions, development

How can i check if a user (not the current user) exists in a group.
The SPGroup object allows to check if the current user is member of the group, but there is no method that checks if a SPUser given in parameter exists or not.

Someone has any idea ?

Answer (score 9):

I use an extension method, like this:

```
    public static bool InGroup(this SPUser User, string GroupName)
    {
        return User.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(g => g.Name.ToLower() == GroupName.ToLower());
    }
```

Then  call it like this:

```
bool inGroup = spuser.InGroup("GroupName");
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to look at the SPUser instead of the SPGroup:
SPUser has a Groups collection you can iterate and look for the group name.

Something like:

```
foreach ( SPGroup group in user.Groups )
    if ( group.Name == groupName )
        // found it
```

Comment: In terms of scalability this is a better solution as you could have groups with potentially large numbers of users, but a user is unlikely to be a member of so many groups.  Its a minor point, but everything helps right?

Comment: Thats a pretty good point Charles. I posted my answer before I saw Anders. Maybe the decision will also include whether you already have an SPGroup/SPUser to iterate?

Comment: You can find some nifty helper methods for this in SPExLib: http://spexlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/22718#339608

Answer (score 3):

you could try SPGroup.ContainsCurrentUser, after having opened your SPSite with the SPUserToken of your target user.

Comment: ContainsCurrentUser is good only when you want to check the current logged in user.  This will not help Alex.  He will have to check the SPUser.Gropus collection.

Comment: I suggested to open the SPSite with the SPUserToken of the target user. This should set the "Current User" context to the target user.

Comment: You are my hero.

Answer (score 0):

The SPGroup has a [Users property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.users.aspx) which is a SPUser collection. Why not just loop through that and look for the SPUser that way?

Comment: This will have performance issues,  since a group can contain many number of users,  This will result in looping many times to check one user.  consider using SPUser.Group collection instead.

Answer (score 0):

For a client-side JavaScript solution, this article describes how to determine if a not-current-user is a member of a group. http://chrissyblanco.blogspot.com/2007/07/determining-whether-user-is-member-of.html